# Netplan issue, cannot do a ip static

Tags: networking, server, netplan

i try to set a two interfaces for my server, ubuntu server 18.04, I share internet in a lan
Here is the configuration

File 01-netcfg.yaml

```
 network:
     version: 2
     renderer: networkd
     ethernets:
         enp4s0:
             dhcp4: true
```

and the 02-netcfg.yaml

```
 network:
     version: 2
     renderer: networkd
     ethernets:
         enp3s0:
             addresses: [192.168.1.1/24, ]
             dhcp4: false
             dhcp6: false
             nameservers:
                 addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

ifconfig returns

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 14:cc:20:02:9e:fe  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::e23f:49ff:fe52:22be  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e0:3f:49:52:22:be  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3154  bytes 479397 (479.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 48  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 199  bytes 28954 (28.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 308  bytes 21480 (21.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 308  bytes 21480 (21.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is netplan apply command

```
netplan --debug apply
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.178: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.178: starting new processing pass
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.179: Processing input file /etc/netplan/02-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.179: starting new processing pass
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.179: enp3s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.179: Configuration is valid
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.179: enp4s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.179: Configuration is valid
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.179: Generating output files..
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.179: NetworkManager: definition enp4s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:2734): DEBUG: 14:28:02.179: NetworkManager: definition enp3s0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:enp4s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:enp3s0 not found in {'enp4s0': {'dhcp4': True}}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.1/24
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: true
  vlans: {}
  wifis: {}

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:device enp4s0 operstate is up, not changing
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: tap0
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp3s0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp4s0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for tap0
```

I don't know why i cannot set ip address, please anyone can help me?

Comment: Simply editing your yaml isn't enough to apply the settings - you DID do `sudo netplan apply` after editing your settings yes?

Comment: no! i do a many times "netplan Apply" and nothing!

Comment: @user535733 doesn't matter if renderer is `networkd` - NM configuration only applies if Network Manager is in use, and by default in servers it's not.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set enp3s0 static IP to the gateway IP.

Comment: And `addresses: [192.168.1.1/24, ]` must be a typo, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe issue is , When the cable is unplugged, the netplan never do a config, Is waiting for a plugg in. Its all, Thanks for your reading